# In drawings, should a repeated pattern but on two different sides of a device have different numbers?

Tags: patent-drawings

In drawings for a utility patent application, if you have a measurement index pattern repeated on two sides of a tool. Each side is shown in the drawings. Should each index set have a different number though they are a repeated pattern? I guessing yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I  think you know, the same thing keeps the same number regardless of the view. I think your question is about something that is an identical feature in a different location. Lets say it is a set of identical screws. All screws will have the same number.

Sometimes similar items are labeled with a prime mark as in 100 and 100'. They are technically different references but give the flavor of being very similar/related.

Answer (score 0):

In utility patent if similar parts are there then you can label them once, it is sufficient.